# How can I test a component with a custom hook param

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I make a checkBox receiving custom hook as a parameter
when I click the checkBox, I can trigger the state so that the mother's component can receive the state.
However, I can't change the value of checkBox in the testing

define custom hook:

```
const useComplete = (complete) => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(complete);
    const toggle = () => setValue(!value);

    return { value, toggle };
};

export default useComplete;
```

define button:

```
import { Checkbox } from "@material-ui/core";
import { green } from "@mui/material/colors";

const label = { inputProps: { "aria-label": "Complete" } };

const CompleteCheckbox = ({ completeHook }) => {
    return (
        <Checkbox
            {...label}
            checked={completeHook.value}
            onChange={() => completeHook.toggle(!completeHook.value)}
            style={{
                color: green[600],
            }}
            data-testid="checkbox"
        />
    );
};

export default CompleteCheckbox;
```

call button:

```
    const completeHook = useComplete(false);
    ...
    return (
      <CompleteButton completeHook={completeHook} /> 
    )
```

testing:

```
describe(CompleteButton, () => {
    it("change to true state", async () => {
        const user = userEvent.setup();
        const { result } = renderHook(() => useComplete(true));
        render(<CompleteButton completeHook={result.current} />);

        const checkboxEl = screen.getByLabelText("Complete");
        expect(checkboxEl.checked).toBe(true);

        // cannot change the button three methods below
        fireEvent.click(checkboxEl);
        fireEvent.change(checkboxEl);
        user.click(checkboxEl);

        expect(checkboxEl.checked).toBe(false);
    });
```

Comment: Try change event since it's a checkbox `fireEvent.change(btn)`

Comment: not working. Thanks for your reminder. I change btn to checkbox to make it more readable